# Importing a weather snapshot/image

Tags: python, image

I'm working on cube satellite project where I've got a code in python, that can translate the Two Line Element codes of satellites and project it's current location on a globe and Mercator map. So far so good. However I need to implement a few more functions for this project, and one of them is the ability to add a most current weather map of the longitude/latitude position of the satellite.

So for now I've decided to go with openweathermap.org since its easy to pull up the map with long/lat parameters.

Such as seen here: [Open Map](http://openweathermap.org/weathermap?basemap=satellite&cities=false&layer=precipitation&lat=30&lon=-20&zoom=4)

However this is obviously not a image I can call out by standard imaging load in techniques. So how would you suggest I go about "snapping" out the picture here? Or is there another approach you may recommend? I'm still quite new to Python and therefore I'm not sure of how best approach this.

Thanks for your time and advice.
Best regards.

Comment: There is something called `selenium` a webdriver that you can program. It basically simulates your browser, you can open it in fullscreen mode and snap an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar task, basically you want to use a webdriver and one of the most popular one is called `selenium`.

1) You have to **install** `selenium` via **pip**

```
pip install selenium
```

2) Additionally you need to **install a webdriver**, In the example I am showing I've used chromedriver, which you can download from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads). Extract and put it some place where it is seen by your `path` variables in your Operating System.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://openweathermap.org/weathermap?basemap=satellite&cities=false&layer=precipitation&lat=39.3003&lon=4.9219&zoom=6')
time.sleep(5)             #Give it some time to load the images
browser.save_screenshot('screenie.png')
browser.quit()
```

[image]

Comment: <3 Much love. Thank you!

Comment: Glad that it helped!

Comment: Can this be done as a background process without opening up the google chrome window, so it just saves it straight to a png, which I can then display in my python GUI?

Comment: There are hacks around it, pushing the window out of focus behind other windows or launching a virtual session, but that is more involved.